# ST_GeomFromText showing outside of map

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to plot some weather.gov grids in PGAdmin, but the polygon is way off the map
[image]

Doing some searching, I believe `ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((x1 y1, x2 y2....xn, yn, x1, y1))')` is what I'm needing to use, and then to cast that to Geography?

```
select ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-121.2163539 42.233639799999999,-121.21070950000001 42.212291899999997,-121.1818863 42.216468899999995,-121.1875249 42.237817199999995,-121.2163539 42.233639799999999))',4326)::geography;
```

the original coordinates that should be contained in this polygon are `42.1958,-121.2182`

I'm probably missing a core concept, but am not sure which... If I remove the SRID, it appears the longitude is correct, but I end up in the northern territories of Canada...

Comment: try https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/220115/276

Comment: @Mapperz if you're referring to the position of the lat,lon... I am using the format of `lon1 lat1, lon2 lat2...`

Comment: That's likely an issue with the *pgAdmin* mapping widget trying to make sense of the `GEOGRAPHY` type - the *Polygon* in your statement is just East of Goodlow Mountain in Oregon. Start reading [the PostGIS topics section](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_GeographyVSGeometry) on the `GEOGRAPHY` type and find answers on GIS.SE for all follow-up questions you may have - bottom line is, you should have a reason to choose `GEOGRAPHY` over the base `GEOMETRY` type, and know a little about the pros and cons of both types.

Comment: Thanks @geozelot! I'll admit I'm in over my head in a bit of this, especially since I'm just really needing small bits of pieces of GIS for this project. I ended up using Poltly to graph the grids and it's working perfectly.

Comment: turns out it was indeed a problem with pgAdmin mapping. the map is tiled\repeated when zoomed out, and for whatever reason I was only seeing 1 of those repeated tiles. and not where it should have been. a reinstall fixed the issue.